# Firebase Security - Apikey

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Is it possible to set a required header as a security rule in firestore?**

So when i use the rest api there should be a `x-apikey = "1234"`

If possible how?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to require a specific header value in Firestore security rules. The only information available in security rules is the authenticated user's token, the path that is being accessed, and of course the information being written (for write operations).

What I sometimes do is make that "API key" part of the path, for example by using it as the document ID. That way the user must specify the correct document ID/API key to be able to read a document.

You may also want to look into [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) if you want to pass user-specific values into your security rules.