# How to acces firebase data using a key

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to secure my firestore data. I have an app that accesses the data from firestore. Currently, my rules allow anyone to read and write. How can I access the data using a key I have in the app? Sort of verify a key before anyone can read or write data.

Here are my current rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/da26189ac1c5bbdea8d374ad8870bd7f - this is why I am asking

Comment: i dont think i have an initializing key

Comment: check this: https://gyazo.com/da26189ac1c5bbdea8d374ad8870bd7f

Comment: Yeah, it's because of these lines `match /{document=**} { allow read, write: if true; }`

Comment: and how can i solve this?

Comment: Well, change it to `false` or delete this line.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/691f2b43680ecf5816c38a8492abb93a - is it better if i add something like this and create an authentication system for the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security rules of your Firestore database only have access to:

- The path that is being accessed (read or written).
- The data that is being written.
- The token of the user that is accessing the data.
- Other data in the database.

There is no way to pass custom data to the security rules in another way, so anything you need will have to be in one of these.

So if you want to pass custom data in both read and write operations, you'll have to do so in either the path or make it part of the user's token, for example by [setting a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) in there.

Also see:

- [Firebase Firestore, send custom id to validate access by rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212475/firebase-firestore-send-custom-id-to-validate-access-by-rules/70217016#70217016)
- [Can I send value with request to Firestore rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648880/can-i-send-value-with-request-to-firestore-rules/54653648#54653648)
- [How can I send the parameter with the firestore get method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343551/how-can-i-send-the-parameter-with-the-firestore-get-method/62345924#62345924)
- [Firebase Security - Apikey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085021/firebase-security-apikey/59092162#59092162)

Comment: so would it be safe to leave it as it is?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/da26189ac1c5bbdea8d374ad8870bd7f - this is why i am concerned

Comment: Since you asked "How to acces firebase data using a key", I answered that question That screenshot is a warning that your database rules allow way too broad access. We've covered that warning quite a few times before, so I recommend having a look at some of these top search results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bfirebase-security%5D+insecure+rules